# Create field codes for citations in word document when using Quarto (or Rmarkdown)

Tags: ms-word, r-markdown, quarto, citations, fieldcodes

**Problem**: I would like the word document output from Quarto (or Rmarkdown) to generate field codes for citations.

**Current Behavior**: The citations are generated as simple text with no underlying field code. This means it is not practical to do further edits to Word document citations.

**Reason**: I work with lots of non-R collaborators. It would be nice to create an "*almost finished*" document using Quarto/Rmd, then finish it using "*old-fashioned*" collaboration in Word methods. But since the citations are simple text without underlying field codes - citation management becomes overly burdensome (i.e., entirely manual numbering, etc...)

I can't seem to find any documentation about doing this in R, or any related posts on SO or Posit.